# Least abstract type in typescript

Tags: typescript, types

I have often used following construction:

```
const v = {
  a: "string1",
  b: "string2",
  c: "string3"
}

const x: keyof typeof v = "a"
```

To assist users of libraries and let the editor show possible version.

In above, if `v` receives the explicit type `{a: string, b: string, c: string}`, this will stop working, as `typeof` resolves to this more general type and does not see individual keys as a part of the type anymore.

However, I want to be able to both type `v` under a type *and* extract the keys of said value. The reason here being that v is a large and complex object witch several incarnations.

Is there way to circumvent this, so that I can both type v and extract keys of a concrete object?

Concretely I have values of following type

```
type T = {
  a: {
    [p: string]: string
  }
  b: {
    [p: string]: string
  }
}
```

With the value:

```
const t: T = {
  a: {
    a1: "n1",
    a2: "n2"
  },
  b: {
    b1: "m1",
    b2: "m2"
  }
}
```

My goal is to make a function with signature `const f: <TE extends T>(a: keyof TE["a"]) => boolean` that recognises the least abstract type of `TE` and `T`. Ie.

- `f("a3")` *should* result in type error
- `f("a2")` *should not* result in type error.

Comment: Hi, the type of `v` is already `{a: string, b: string, c: string}`. Please add an example where the type fails as you said in `this will stop working, as typeof resolves to this more general type and does not see individual keys as a part of the type anymore.`

Comment: Just drop the annotation `T` from the declaration of `t`. All it does is remove the type information that you want to retain.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I just clarified that I am not able to drop the annotation of the object I want to extract keys from as there are several of them and I need typing there. Otherwise the `{ ... } as const` is what I would have gone for.

Comment: @ShivamSingla I added an example of what should and should not make the program break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing. The only solution I found is using a factory function:

```js
type T = {
  a: {
    [p: string]: string
  }
  b: {
    [p: string]: string
  }
}

function createT<TE extends T>(obj: TE): TE {
   return obj;
}

const t = createT({
   a: {
    a1: "n",
    a2: "n"
  },
  b: {
    b1: "n",
    b2: "n"
  }
});

type TE = typeof t;

const f: (a: keyof TE["a"]) => boolean = () => true;
f('a1');
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=30&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UDeAoKUCGAuZb1QG0wcBnYAJwEsA7AcwF1SKba8BfPAIx1X0OKhkqdRoOZ12KDigBmAV2oBjYJQD21KIvIQMwCDAA8MAKJQIADz3UAJiVgA+ABSrOAKxwmAlB9O9024DlyDRdXAG4pFBRFdTIoYARNbV19Rz9MHjx0DABGHAAianyAGizMACYCovZS9G5cPk48qEKSss5Klur0DjZPCJRQSFhTRCGIVRl4gZjqOJkcR2woAGsIEEmRgnyMfPpPBHsoTlVVABsdDURHA-gjijkIAZlHAHJc1-6UIA)

Comment: Clever, thanks!

Obviously the typescript type system is not not build for this task in general. But this is a good solution. A couple of things:

1. `createT` does not restrict `obj`. Ie, it can legally hold more information than specified by `T` (TE _extends_ T) - For my use case this is reasonable.
2. Obviously obj should be be explicitly type before being fed to `createT` such as `v: T = ... ; t = createT(v);` (I fell in this one at my first attempt of migrating this solution)
3. Errors on `obj` are not presented beautifully. But for my case this is also acceptable.